# How do I set the colors of the points in a plotly scatter plot with a list of rgba values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I have pre-calculated the colors for each of the points.

```
cmap = ScalarMappable(...)
colors = [cmap.to_rgba(val) for val in vals]

# ax.scatter(xvals,yvals, c=colors) # my matplotlib function

import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter(x=xvals,y=yvals,color_discrete_sequence=colors)
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)
```

But the graph seems to show whatever colors it wants. How do I set my plotly chart colors such that the plotly chart is the same as the mpl chart?

---

On second thought, I may have found a bug.  When I switched to a dataframe format, the colors worked:

```
df = DataFrame()
df['foo'] = xvals
df['bar'] = yvals
fig = px.scatter(df,x='foo',y='bar', color_discrete_sequence=colors)
```

But I am in the first 15 min of my `plotly` learning curve, so "I dunno"...

Comment: Could you share a sample of your data?